# Crontab: run a command every 12 hours and 5 minutes

Tags: cron

Is it possibile to run a crontab script every N hours AND M minutes?
I can't find a way to do that, is the following rule valid? (I prefer not to wait 12 hours to know it :))

```
5 */12 * * * mycommand
```

In alternative, 12 hours and 5 minutes are 725 minutes, but I doubt that I can write something like:

```
*/725 * * * * mycommand
```

Am I missing a trivial way to do that or what I ask is impossible?

Comment: No, I don't think it's possible. The fields are processed independently, and the minutes field is just minutes within the hour. You can run the script every 5 minutes, and put code in the script to determine how long it has been since the previous run.

Comment: What's the use case for this?

Comment: The use case is an update that has to be done after 12 hours, and not every 12 exact hours, so I was looking for a basic crontab solution, and I was curious if it was possible with only crontab, but I'll ad some basic scripting to do that. Thanks for your comment